# Slider images doesn't appear in the container

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexslider, owl-carousel

I'm trying to use a slider in some blogger theme, I've tried both Flexslider and Owl Carousel, both perfectly worked in the sidebar of the page but when I try to put them in the main container it just doesn't show the images in the slider, I mean it fully loads the slider and everything but it kind of seems that the images are hidden or something, it's like a slider with a solid white background, just ZERO images, they're like underneath or sth. 
now does anyone has any idea what the heck is going on here?? please help
I've used this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

  autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

  items : 4,
  itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
  itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]

});

});
```

and

```
<div id="owl-demo">

<div class="item"><img src="assets/owl1.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="assets/owl2.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="assets/owl3.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="assets/owl4.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="assets/owl5.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="assets/owl6.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="assets/owl7.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="assets/owl8.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>

</div>
```

and this

```
#owl-demo .item{
  margin: 3px;
}
#owl-demo .item img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

in this container:

```
<div class="widget popular-post">
<h2 class="widget-title"><span class="icon-coffee pull-right"></span>The Title</h2>
...
</div>
```

with this style:

```
.widget {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

and the slider works in the first container but not the other ones! infact I assigned another slider like this for the other container:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owlslider").owlCarousel({

  autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

  items : 4,
  itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
  itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]

  });

});
```

what is wrong here???

Comment: What if you share a bit of your code?

Comment: Share the code which you have tried so far.

Comment: I just did ... help me